# gcc 4.7.3 with O1,O2 or O3 creates faulty code

Tags: c++, gcc

With gcc 4.7.3 my application works fine without optimization,
but when i use -O1, -O2, or -O3 a strange thing happens:
a non-NULL pointer becomes NULL from one step to the next.

```
iResult = ppAG[0]->prune(bCut);
if (iResult >= 0) {
    printf("save %p in [%s]\n", ppAG[0], sOutput);
    ppAG[0]->saveBin(sOutput);
    printf("showing ancestorinfo for %p\n", ppAG[0]);
    ppAG[0]->showAncestorInfo(false);
}
```

The line with `saveBin` is executed fine, but in the next line it crashes.
The debugger shows that ppAG turns to NULL when i step from the fourth to the fifth line here.

Interestingly the code does *not* crash, when i comment out the call to `prune`,
even if `prune` only contains a print statement.

I checked with valgrind: the non-optimized code has no errors, and for the optimized i only get

```
----(snip)----
save 0x64d1780 in [smalltest_040.ag]
==15401== Invalid read of size 8
==15401==    at 0x402D86: main (stdio2.h:104)
==15401==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
----(snip)----
```

I suspect this is inside the print statement on the fifth line.

With gcc 4.6.3 this does not happen.

Is there an explanation for this behavior, or is it a bug?

Comment: A compiler producing "buggy" code with optimizations turned on is almost always buggy code and hence your own fault. You probably have UB somewhere.

Comment: Sounds very much like you've got a memory leak of buffer overrun. Check the code that runs before to make sure that you do not use uninitialized variables or pointers.

Comment: btw. we have already gcc 4.8 and 4.9 out. In any case, without knowing what your code does, we can not say if its correct.

Comment: @MatsFredriksson the OP says valgrind didnt' find any errors with his code, though we shouldn't think it _guarantees_ anything...

Comment: Debugging an optimised build can be psychedelic - the execution order of the code doesn't match the source any more, breakpoints aren't where you think, and variables mysteriously change values. You'll need to look at the assembly to see what's going on. Most likely you have undefined behaviour somewhere (and it can be almost anywhere, even *after* the point where things go weird).

Comment: Are you using threads? Optimisation may produce code which runs at different speeds and expose issues with state which is not synchronised correctly.

Comment: My guess would be that the `saveBin()` function is overwriting `ppAG[0]`, but you've not posted that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how to debug this.

1. Run your program under GDB, and set a breakpoint on the `saveBin` line:

   ```
   (gdb) break <file>:<line>
   ```
2. Let the program get to that point:

   ```
   (gdb) run
   ```
3. Create a watchpoint for `ppAG[0]`:

   ```
   (gdb) watch ppAG[0]
   ```
4. Let the program continue:

   ```
   (gdb) continue
   ```

The program should then halt on the instruction that writes the `NULL` to the pointer. You can then `backtrace`, `list`, `dissassemble`, check `info reg` to narrow down the problem.

It might be a buffer overrun on the stack (valgrind would normally detect that on the heap), or a conditional with undefined behaviour, or it might just be a real compiler bug.

Comment: @asm: thanks - this helped a lot. I was able to track down the location where i had written outside of my buffer, as you (and Mats) suggested. Now also the optimized version runs correctly.